# About return value of Integer.toString(char)

Tags: java, string, char, integer

What is the possible value for `char` variable `c` if `Integer.toString(c)` returns `1087`?

Comment: `char c = (char) 1087;` ?

Comment: There's no `Integer.toString(char)` method that I'm aware of. Perhaps you meant `Integer.toString(int)` that you happen to be calling with a `char` argument, using the implicit conversion from `char` to `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Integer.toString()` with a `char`:

```
char c = ...
Integer.toString(c);
```

the `char`(16 bit) will be `converted` to an `int` (32 bit) by adding leading  zeros.

That means if the output is 1087, then the original char's binary is `10000111111`(in hex 0x043F). It should be `п` accoding to this [table](https://unicode-table.com/en/#043F).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c = 'п';
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(c)); // 1087
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do Character.toString(c) instead of Integer.toString(c) and get the character representation instead of the integer representation.